# Nginx fails to retrieve server resources from localhost

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx server running on a VM with certbot (running other applications fine). I am trying to run a clojure/clojurescript application (JAR file), which works fine locally, to serve a web app. The application is launching the `index.html` fine, however it is failing to retrieve the associated resources, both js and css.

> Loading failed for the  with source “https://example.com/js/main/main.js”. server:2:875

My Nginx config for said server is:

```
location /server/ {
    auth_basic "Server";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pw_file;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    #proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help. I am thinking that `proxy_pass` is not working right, as it appears to be trying to get the resources from the domain not localhost?

I have tried messing with the `proxy_set_header` values but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: You've defined nginx with /server route... What's supposed to handle /js route?

Comment: Ahh, I figured it was getting passed to example.com/server/js which would be -> localhost:300/js 

How would I route the requests from the application to go to localhost:3000/request instead or example.com/request?

Comment: Do you necessarily need /server instead of `location /`? The other option is to change the returned html to render a different path for static assets, rather than modify nginx

Comment: I have a couple other servers running through nginx and this one is just a sub domain for testing. Would using `rewrite` allow me to reroute all the src directories to their correct location?

Comment: I'm not sure rewrite would work. There's a `try_files` directive, but if you have script tags that only load `src="/js/..."`, then your nginx server needs to define that location, and any separate server shouldn't share that path

Comment: I tried rewrite my `src` tags to `src="/server/js/...` which worked but it has interfered with a bunch of my server side js code. Is there no way to get nginx to route all requests from the subdomain to be at that subdomain?

Comment: Subdomain is a DNS registrar thing, not nginx config, which are just location paths/routes. In Flask framework, for example, you just update one config and use a template function in the html to render the correct value. I assume clojure is similar

Comment: Ended up just getting a separate domain. Was the easiest way! Thanks for your help.